Offset after georeferencing Comoros topo map to WGS 84
I have some scanned paper topographic maps of Comoros with the following projection information:

I believe that this corresponds to EPSG:2999.  However, after getting good control points in the QGIS georeferencer and reprojecting to EPSG:4326, the maps are consistently offset by a little over a kilometer to the northwest when compared to Google satellite imagery.  Any thoughts on where to look for the culprit?

Check the Datum on your control points.

There's a Grand Comoros geographic coordinate reference system (CRS), EPSG::4646, in the EPSG dataset that EPSG::2999 (Grand Comoros / UTM 38 South is based upon. There's also a coordinate operation (transformation) between Grand Comoros and WGS84, EPSG::5521, which has relatively large XYZ offsets: -963.0,  510.0, -359.0. The accuracy of the transformation is uknown.
